# XDb collection unavailable exceptions while Xdb is completely disabled

Tags: xdb, session-state

My Sitecore 9.3 website has Xdb and Xdb.Tracking disabled but still CM server error logs always have some XDb collection unavailable exceptions. Is Xdb still coming into picture? These exceptions are on  sessionEnd:batch:starting' event.

Answer (score 2):

Verify the following sections

1. Navigate to Showconfig.aspx page and make sure Xdb.Enabled is false and Xdb.Tracking.Enabled is set to false.
2. Recycle AppPools of all the default xDB environments or reset the IIS to remove any possible caching scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with both xdb and xdb tracking disabled and it appears to be a sitecore 9.3 bug, so i got this workaround from sitecore support:

As a workaround please try to disable in the \App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Tracking\Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config file:

```
<events>
<event name="sessionEnd:batch:starting">
<handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Events.BatchEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics" method="OnBatchStarting" />
</event>
<event name="sessionEnd:batch:ended">
<handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Events.BatchEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics" method="OnBatchEnded" />
```